# ENOENT(No such files or directory ) for new android versions (3.0+)

Tags: android

I am new in developing android apps, Every time my application runs on an android 6.0 emulator I can not download files and install (.zip) from in phone memory but shows Error: open failed: ENOENT(No such files or directory ) so I am assuming that the code below is causing this error.. Can anyone assist me.

```
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File downloadFolder = new File(sdcard.getPath() + Constants.DOWNLOAD_FOLDER);
        if (!downloadFolder.isDirectory()) {
            boolean success = downloadFolder.mkdirs();
            Log.d(TAG, "Creating download directory success: " + success);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where do you get this error? What part of the code fails? What is the path which is accessed (and not found)? Does it indeed exist (did you check?)? Also, please cut your code down to a minimal example demonstrating the problem and only the problem, not your whole app or activity.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem comes from the name of the folder of downloads(Constants.DOWNLOAD_FOLDER). Maybe it is not set right in Constants class. Also I suggest you to try the Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, after checking the documentation here (and if that's what you need):  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS
As far as I know, the Downloads folder may have different names on storages. Note also that  Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS is added only after API 8.
Hope this helps!